# Typescript Errors: View' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am having trouble figuring out how to type my components properly.

Sometimes everything seems to work, and other times I get the following error message:

> Type '({}: TestProps) => View' is not assignable to type 'FC'.

Below is the most basic component I can create and I still get the error..

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

type TestProps = {};
const Test: React.FC<TestProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                Some text
            </Text>
        </View>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `React.FC<TestProps>` to `React.FunctionComponent<TestProps>`, or `React.ComponentType<TestProps>` if you don't need generic parameter for the props:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

type TestProps = {};

const Test: React.FunctionComponent<TestProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                Some text
            </Text>
        </View>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue, still getting this error with your above code:

```const Test: React.FunctionComponent<TestProps>
Type '({}: TestProps) => View' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<TestProps>'.
  Type 'View' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
    Type 'NativeMethods & ViewComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, key ts(2322)
```

Comment: That said, what is the main difference between FC ad FunctionComponent, and when should I use one over the other when defining a component in React Native?

Comment: ```React.FunctionComponent``` is equivalent to ```React.FC```, the only difference is that it does not include a generic type parameter for the props, that why it suppose can avoid the error you posted.